# Rename iOS device without needing to restore

Tags: itunes, restore, ipad, ios, jailbreak

I have just restored my iPad but for some reason (most likely because I pressed space bar on that text field but do you not remember) my newly restored iPad is called "iPad" rather than "my name's iPad". Is there a way to rename your iPad without having to go though the restore process again?

Note: Jailbreaking is not of the question.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Connect your device and open iTunes.
2. In the source list (the left-hand column of iTunes), double-click on the name of the device.
3. Type the new name for your device and press Return on the keyboard.
4. Sync the device (press Sync in the bottom right corner of the screen).

Comment: Oh right. I right click'd to see if that option was there but I didn't think of the obvious thing, thanks though.